# Kotlin Android Studio: org.junit.ComparisonFailure with NBSP

Tags: java, android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin

I have this code

```
@Test
fun price_twelve_cupcakes() {
    val viewModel = OrderViewModel()
    viewModel.setQuantity(12)
    viewModel.price.observeForever {}
    assertEquals("$27,00", viewModel.price.value)
}
```

And I get this
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfyQ0.png)

And This [Comparison Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXcgj.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same issue with the NBSP sign! Spent some time to figure out what to do with the tests

TL;DR:

1. Pass locale in your string formatters
2. For tests of locales that use NBSP instead of a space (French, Ukrainian etc.) paste the unicode version of NBSP (\u00A0) in your test string

So

```
assertEquals("27,00 Br", priceToCheck)
```

should become

```
assertEquals("27,00\u00A0Br", priceToCheck)
```

Also note that different locales not only have different grouping sign (comma, dot, space, NBSP etc.) but also a different cents separator (comma, dot)

It's caused by Locale's string formatting settings and involves DecimalFormat, String.format, NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
If you want your string to be formatted in a stable way no matter what default locale is set, you can use either DecimalFormat(pattern of choice) or pass the Locale you want (say Locale("en","IE") for Ireland)